# AWK: Generate two output files with different OFS

Tags: awk

Disclaimer: I know this problem can *easily* be solved using `tr` and others, but I am curious to make it work in `awk` only.

I want to generate two output files (same content) with different OFS using `awk`. Here is what I tried so far, which I know is wrong btw:

```
awk '$14==1 {

{print $0 > "output.txt"}
{OFS=","}
{print $0 > "output.csv"}

}' inputfile.txt
```

(the input file is tab-separated). When I run this I get two files (properly filtered by `$14==1`) with the exact same content and still the original OFS. I know I could explicitly tell the print statement to use "," by doing

```
{print $1","$2...}
```

or

```
{printf("%s,%s,,,\n",$1,$2...)}
```

but the input file has over 50 columns, and I feel there is an elegant solution to this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what I meant is that both output files are exactly the same (`diff output.txt output.csv` returns nothing), so my `OFS=","` line didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just `print` without changing the value of `$x`, the `OFS` will not be applied anyway.

You can:

```
 awk -F',' '{print $0 > "file1"}{gsub(FS, " ");print $0 > "file2"}' input
```

or to make use of default `OFS`:

```
awk -F',' '{print $0 > "file1";$1=$1;print $0 > "file2"}' input
```

In above codes, `$1=$1` **changed** the value of `$1` even if with the same value, this will apply the `OFS`.

Answer (score 2):

To use 2 different OFS values for 2 different output files even if neither is the FS used in the input file or you have other reasons to rebuild the output record:

```
awk '$14==1 {
    $1=$1; print > "output.txt"     # use the original OFS value
    ofs=OFS; OFS=","
    $1=$1; print > "output.csv"     # use the alternate OFS value
    OFS=ofs
}' inputfile.txt
```

Given tab-separated input like you have the above would create a blank-separated output .txt file and a comma-separated output .csv file. If you want the .txt file to be tab-separated then you need to set OFS as a tab (and you'll want to set FS to a tab too if your input can contain blank chars or empty fields).

Also consider this:

```
awk -v ofs1='|' -v ofs2=',' '$14==1 {
    OFS=ofs1; $1=$1; print > "output.txt"     # use ofs1
    OFS=ofs2; $1=$1; print > "output.csv"     # use ofs2
}' inputfile.txt
```